# Issues with Consul ACL caching

Tags: acl, consul

Myself and my colleagues are currently having an issue with Consul ACLs.   We have an ACL primary datacentre in location A, and another datacentre in location B connecting to it, and a client C that connects to B. We set a KV ACL in A and verify that it works in C. in B and C we have acl.policy_ttl set to (e.g.) 1800s or 259200s in /etc/consul.d/consul.json. We then shut down A and validate that we can still access (write to) the KV store from C. At some seemingly random time later, we start to get the message "ACL not found" when writing to the KV from C. how can we configure this to reliably cache ACLs for a fixed period of time in B so that C can still use the KV store when A is unavailable?

Our current consul version is 1.4.4.  I would appreciate any help you can offer on this issue.

Answer (score 0):

You need to set `acl.token_ttl` as well ([documentation](https://www.consul.io/docs/agent/options.html#acl_token_ttl)) `acl.policy_ttl` caches policies, but `acl.token_ttl` sets cache for the issued ACL tokens, which is what you want as well. By edfault this `Token TTL` is 30s, so I'm guessing in your case the `random time` was less than 1 minute (datacenter B had cache up to 30s and client C had cached up to 30s).

Hope that helps.